# cant figure out simply .htaccess redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

So I have changed my url strcture and I'm trying to redirect

http://www.mysite.com/search-example/1.html

where example = search term (can be anything) and 1 equals the page number, to

http://www.mysite.com/search-example-1.html ?

It needs to be dynamic depending on their search term and the page number.

Comment: http://www.mysite.com/search-example/1.html   to   http://www.mysite.com/search-example-1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot test it at the moment, but maybe this will do the trick:

```
Redirect 301 /search-(.*)/(.*).html http://www.mysite.com/search-$1-$2.html
```

Comment: You want: `RedirectMatch 301 /search-(.*)/(.*).html http://www.mysite.com/search-$1-$2.html`